# Laravel lighthouse morphOne mutation

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I want to allow users to upload images with their post but also have the ability to allow the users to upload images for the landingspage via a morphOne relation.

I set up my models according to the laravel docs but can provide them if needed.

than in my `schema.graphql` file I have the following

// schema.graphql

```
type Query

type Mutation



union Imageable = Blog | Landingspage


#import graphql/blog/*.graphql
#import graphql/landingspage/*.graphql
#import graphql/image/image.graphql
```

inside of the `image.graphql` file I have the following

// image.graphql

```
extend type Mutation {
    createImage(input: ImageInput! @spread): Image @create
    updateImage(input: ImageInput! @spread): Image @update
    deleteImage(input: ImageInput! @spread): Image @delete
}

type Image {
    id: ID!
    url: String!
    imageable: Imageable! @morphTo
}

input ImageInput {
    id: ID!
    url: String
    imageable:ImageableMorphTo
}

input ImageableMorphTo {
    connect: ImageableInput
    disconnect: Boolean
    delete: Boolean
}

input ImageableInput {
    type: String!
    id: ID!
}
```

and lastly in my `blog.graphql` file I have this

// blog.graphql

```
extend type Query {
    blogs: [Blog!]! @all  @orderBy(column: "created_at", direction: DESC)
    blog(slug: String! @eq): Blog @find
}

extend type Mutation {
    createBlog(input: CreateBlogInput @spread): Blog @create
}


type Blog {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    big_text: String!
    small_text: String!
    slug: String!
    category_id: Int
    created_at: DateTime!
    updated_at: DateTime!
    image: Image @morphOne
}


input CreateBlogInput {
    title: String!
    big_text: String!
    small_text: String!
    category_id: Int,
    image: ImageInput
}
```

Now when I go to the `graphql-playground` and create the mutation

```
mutation ($input: CreateBlogInput ){
  createBlog(input:$input){
    id
    title
    small_text
    big_text
    image{
      id
      url
    }
  }
}
```

with the following input

```
{
  "input": {
    "title": "image-test",
    "big_text": "big_text",
    "small_text": "small_text",
    "category_id": 2,
    "image": {
      "id": 3,
      "url": "https://cats.example/cute"
      }
    }
  }
```

my response is this

```
{
  "data": {
    "createBlog": {
      "id": "7",
      "title": "image-test",
      "small_text": "small_text",
      "big_text": "big_text",
      "image": null
    }
  }
}
```

How do I make image not null anymore? I tried to reverse engineer the example at

https://lighthouse-php.com/master/eloquent/nested-mutations.html#morphto

but this only shows you how to create a image and connect a post (or blog) to it, but I want to create a post with an image.

Comment: Explain your problem with very clear format, Add only required code.

Comment: Edited my question, this code is required if you want to understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you want that your `image` field were not null, just add a `!`, so:

```
type Blog {
  # ...
  image: Image! @morphOne
}
```

Secondly, if you want to create a Blog with an Image, the input should be like:

```
extend type Mutation {
    createBlog(input: CreateBlogInput @spread): Blog @create
}

input CreateBlogInput {
    title: String!
    big_text: String!
    small_text: String!
    category_id: Int,
    image: BlogImageRelationInput
}

input BlogImageRelationInput {
    upsert: UpsertImageInput
}

input UpsertImageInput {
    id: ID
    url: String
}
```